# Installing Wolfram engine without sudo?

Tags: installation, free-wolfram-engine

Is it possible to install the free Wolfram Engine https://www.wolfram.com/engine/  on Ubuntu without sudo permission?

I can install Mathematica on Ubuntu without sudo permision, but I don't know how to install the free Wolfram Engine without sudo command.

Comment: check this for a extract script. https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=wolframengine

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, unlike VSCode or other electron based solutions, it doest use shared app-data directories, which does not require root permissions.

However, using docker container might be a a good solution